# How to programmatically change binding when datacontext changes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0

I have a custom control that allows the consumer to send in markup that will be parsed into `Inlines`, and it will try to match a given `Command` name with its appropriate ICommand. I have this working except in the case where the `DataContext` is not set yet. I know that storing the markup and reloading it upon `DataContextChanged` is not appropriate, but I cannot seem to find anything that works yet. I have tried `BindingExpression` and `Binding` to no avail as I do not see a way to attach them to a `Hyperlink`

Comment: What makes you say "I know that storing the markup and reloading it upon DataContextChanged is not appropriate" ?

Comment: It just seems like a waste of resources, as well as has the potential to flash for users with slower computers

Answer (score 1):

> I know that storing the markup and reloading it upon DataContextChanged is not appropriate

If you're going to be building a binding to `ICommand` instances within the `DataContext`, this is likely the only option that will make sense.

Otherwise, you'd never be able to correct the binding when the data context is changed.

Comment: See my answer. I think my question writeup may have mis-explained my goal as I see your point in a more direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into some other code, I realized that this is all I needed to do:

```
hyperlink.SetBinding(Hyperlink.CommandProperty, new Binding(description.Command));
```

The WPF code picks it up generically...I will need to reflect to see exactly what it does, but it works. I could not set the `Command` property directly, but this worked :)

Comment: This won't work if the DataContext is not yet set unless that ICommand is a DelegateCommand that the developer will have to manually call RaiseCanExecuteChange()

Comment: Interesting, have you tried if it still works when you change your datacontext? As long as the DataContext's command property is there?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Yes, in fact I start with it not there and the datacontext comes in after loading